# WordPress: Unable to read custom field that is part of a fields group

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, customization

I added a new custom field to a fields group to be used only to render the homepage. When trying read and display the contents of this field with the code below, nothing happens. I am sure the way to read custom field is how it should be. I don't get any error message. Could you please help fix this? This is being done on a WordPress site.

```
<div class="bg-white-base relative pt-row pb-row pl pr">
  <div class="wrap-x">
    <div class="inside mini">
      
      <?php if ( $headline = get_sub_field( 'slider_-_h1' ) ) : ?>
      <h2 class="mb color-purple-base">
        <?php echo $headline; ?>
      </h2>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if ( $subheadline = get_sub_field( 'slider_-_h2' ) ) : ?>
      <h3 class="mb alt-heading h5">
        <?php echo $subheadline; ?>
      </h3>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if ( $text_area = get_sub_field( 'slider-_shortcode' ) ) : ?>
      <article class="body-area mt2x">
        <?php echo $text_area; ?>
      </article>
      <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `get_sub_field()` is supposed to be use inside a loop like `while( have_rows('hero') ): the_row(); ........ endwhile;` https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/ can you show it to us ?

Comment: I thought a loop is necessary only if the fields group has repeater fields.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. Please convert your comment into an answer so I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_sub_field()` is supposed to be use inside a loop. When you use a group, you may use a loop like :

```
while( have_rows('hero') ): the_row();
........
endwhile;
```

Everything is explained here : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/

Comment: Thanks for helping save me a lot of time.